# How can I compile dynamically added `ng-controller`?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

So I have `$("#control-panel").prepend("<div ng-controller="asd"></div>");`. It seems that trying to access it via `angular.elements(document.getElementById("control-panel")).scope()` does not load models and `$scope` functions that was intially set in `app.controller("asd", function ($scope) { $scope.try_me = "asd"; })`.

So how can I attach a new appended DOM with its corresponding AngularJS controller?

Comment: I don't think JQuery and Angular are a good mix. You should consider finding an "Angular" way of doing something. If you want to add a new element in Angular, then you should have a list of items from which the DOM elements are derived, and adding an item to the list will add them to the DOM. You shouldn't use JQuery when trying to add a DOM element with Angular.

Comment: You [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) it.

Comment: I did using `$compile(angular.element(document.getElementById("id-to-asd-controller")).contents())($scope);` and it does not work.

Comment: You don't mention that in your question though. It sounds like you will want to update your question with the code blocks that show the issues you are encountering. Without that we may not be able to help much.